# libcurl skipping some bytes while downloading files only from python simple server and only in android emulator running on windows

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, android-emulator, libcurl

First I compiled libcurl on my Mac with following script.

```
ARCH=$1
API_VER="21"

if [ $ARCH == "x86" ]; then
    HOST="i686"
    DEST_DIR="x86"
elif [ $ARCH == "x86_64" ]; then
    HOST="x86_64"
    DEST_DIR="x86_64"
elif [ $ARCH == "arm" ]; then
    HOST="arm"
    DEST_DIR="armeabi-v7a"
elif [ $ARCH == "arm64" ]; then
    HOST="aarch64"
    DEST_DIR="arm64-v8a"
fi

if [ $HOST == "arm" ]; then
    CLANG="armv7a-linux-androideabi$API_VER-clang"
    HOST="$HOST-linux-androideabi"
else
    CLANG="$HOST-linux-android$API_VER-clang"
    HOST="$HOST-linux-android"
fi

NDK_VER="20"
NDK_HOME="/Users/visor24-mac/Android-NDK/android-ndk-r$NDK_VER"
SYSROOT="$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot"
INCPATH="/Users/visor24-mac/Project/External/prebuilt/include/android/${DEST_DIR}/openssl"
LIBPATH="/Users/visor24-mac/Project/External/prebuilt/lib/android/${DEST_DIR}"
PREFIX="/Users/visor24-mac/Project/External/curl/build/android/$ARCH"

export PATH="$NDK_HOME/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin":"$PATH"
export CC="$CLANG"
export CPPFLAGS="-I${INCPATH}"
export CFLAGS="--sysroot ${SYSROOT} -O3"
export LDFLAGS="-L${LIBPATH} --sysroot ${SYSROOT}"

./configure --disable-shared --enable-static --host=$HOST --prefix=$PREFIX
make -j 4 && make install || exit 2
```

Then codes for downloading url.

```
static size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
    size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, (FILE *)stream);
    l_info << written;
    if ( size * nmemb != written )
        l_error;

    g_written += written;

    return written;
}

static void DownloadURL( const std::string& url, const std::string& fileName )
{
    CURL* curlHandle = nullptr;
    FILE* file = nullptr;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curlHandle = curl_easy_init();
    auto rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str() );
    rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0L );
    rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L );
    rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L );
    rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L );
    rc = curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data );

    file = fopen( fileName.c_str(), "wb" );
    if ( file )
    {
        //curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, stdout );
        curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, file );
        rc = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
        if ( rc != CURLE_OK )
        {
            l_error << curl_easy_strerror( rc );
        }
        else
        {
            l_info << "CURL DOWNLOAD SUCCESS!!!!";
        }

        fclose( file );
    }

    curl_easy_cleanup( curlHandle );
    curl_global_cleanup();
}
```

And python simple server.

> python3 -m http.server

Everything works fine except in one case.
libcurl skips one byte each several times in the middle resulting a few bytes short file from original, with following error.

> Transferred a partial file

That happens only in emulator running on windows and only when downloading from my python simple server.

Real phone device works fine.
Emulator on Mac works fine.
Even emulator on Win works fine when I download some random web contents.

I can continue to work on my Mac and it makes this problem gone, but it's a bit annoying because Windows PC was my primary dev machine.
And I'm very curious what can cause this.
As I said libcurl is compiled on Mac for all ABIs, then I linked them with my app in Android Studio on my Win PC.
So even if ABI is same for both libcurl and my app, cross-compile host OS isn't.
Can this cause a problem?
Any ideas?

Comment: I doubt the issue is with cross-compilation; the host OS might be the same but the cross-compiling toolchain is.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you detect the missing bytes? Is there a pattern to which bytes get skipped? I have a suspicion but I would rather see evidence first.

Comment: @Botje I downloaded a plain ascii file and used a diff tool to compare to orginal one. There were infrequent missing characters (one character each) but I'm not sure about the pattern. It was sometimes whitespace characters and sometimes it wasn't. Maybe it's first or last byte of write chunk but I didn't check that yet.

Comment: When you use the command-line `curl` tool to get this file, does the `Content-Length` in the response headers match the size of the response body? Otherwise libcurl is right to complain

Comment: @Botje I didn't test that yet. I'm currently not able to run the test but will do that later. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @Botje OK. I received the header with "curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, header );". It shows  'Content-Length: 57322', which is correct, but actual body file is only 57315 bytes. I also did it with command line 'curl - I url' and it also shows 57322 bytes.

Comment: And `curl uri | wc -c ` produces 57322 bytes?

Comment: @Botje Yes it does.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: @visor24 I'm facing the exact same issue. (partial file download when using libcurl in android app on emulator running on Windows). Did you figure out the root-cause / workaround?

Comment: @ShrukulHabib Sorry for late response. I couldn't resolve the problem, I just switched my http server to tcp/ip based one.